# How can solve the error is "404 page not found" using react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

this is navbar code. there has no problem. it's working well.

#### navBar.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './navbar.css'
import { Link, useLoaderData, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../../Context/Context';



const NavBar = ({params}) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
    const { navItem, subMenuMaps } = useContext(AuthContext)

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleMenu = (t) => {
        setToggle(t)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className='nav-bar-container'>
                <div className='mobile-view' onClick={() => handleMenu(!toggle)}><i className="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></div>
                <div className='nav-bar'>
                    {
                        navItem.map((menu) =>
                            navItem && <Link className='nav-item' to={ menu?.menu_label === 'home' ? `/`: subMenuMaps[menu.menu_id] ? '/'  : `/${menu.menu_label.replace(/ /g, '_')}/${menu.id}` } key={menu.id}>{menu.menu_label === "home" ? <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-house-chimney"></i>:<>{menu?.menuassign?.menu_title_bangla}</>}
                                {subMenuMaps[menu.menu_id] && (
                                    <div className='hover-items-container dropdown'>
                                        <div className="hover-items">
                                            {subMenuMaps[menu.menu_id].map(submenu => (
                                                <Link className='hover-item' key={submenu.id} to={`/${menu.menu_label.replace(/ /g, '_')}/${submenu.submenu_label.replace(/ /g, '_')}/${submenu.id}`}>{submenu?.submenuassign?.submenu_title_bangla}</Link>
                                            ))}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </Link>
                        )
                    }
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className='payment' href="https://live.academyims.com/Student_Portal">ফি পেমেন্ট</a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className='mobile-nav-var-container'>
                <div className={!toggle ? 'nav-bar-mobile' : 'display'}>
                    {
                        navItem.map((menu) => <>
                            <Link className='nav-item' to={ menu?.menu_label === 'home' ? `/`: subMenuMaps[menu.menu_id] ? '/'  : `/${menu.menu_label.replace(/ /g, '_')}/${menu.id}` } onClick={() => handleMenu(true)} key={menu.id}> {menu?.menuassign?.menu_title_bangla}
                            </Link>
                        <div className='hover-item-mobile-view'>
                             <div className="hover-items">
                             {subMenuMaps[menu.menu_id] && (
                                    <div className='hover__mobile'>
                                        <div className="hover-items">
                                            {subMenuMaps[menu.menu_id].map(submenu => (
                                                <Link className='hover-item' key={submenu.id} to={`/${menu.menu_label.replace(/ /g, '_')}/${submenu.submenu_label.replace(/ /g, '_')}/${submenu.id}`}>{submenu?.submenuassign?.submenu_title_bangla}</Link>
                                            ))}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         </>
                        )
                    }
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className='payment' href="https://live.academyims.com/Student_Portal">ফি পেমেন্ট</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

this is my route. there has no error. route working well. when i click on submenu data also showed.
the problem is, after go to the submenu if reload the page again then show "404 page not found". Problem is happened if page reload. Please, help me to solve this. Thank you.

```
{
 path:'/:menuLabel/:menuId',
       loader:async({params})=>{
             return params
          },
      element:<BoardResult/>
 },
```

Comment: very little detail, could you make sandbox example so that we can see whats happening. Issue might be when you reload the page, request goes directly to server if this is the case you need to Define a catch-all route to serve the index.html for all unknown routes

Comment: @JamshaidTariq this is my demo website (https://srijaneebidyaniketan.edu.bd/) you can check any sub menu then you understand the problem is.

Comment: Your server is not configured correctly. All routes should return `index.html` if you want client-side routing

Comment: Same comment as Konrad. Where/how are you building and deploying your app? Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's already a relevant section covering your host/server. If there isn't then you'll need to consult your host's documentation (*if it exists*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your server is not configured correctly. All routes should return index.html if you want client-side routing.

you need to do something like this.

```
// Define a catch-all route to serve the index.html for all unknown routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct, but should be a comment since we don't know what or how OP is hosting or serving their app, which basically (*very likely*) invalidates the second part of your answer.